# Removing all data before the first '-' in a column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, substring

My spreadsheet currently has a column C with rows of data that have this structure below:

`123 - abc - xyz`

I want my VBA code to remove all the data before the first - including the - so that the column C would look like this:

`abc - xyz`

My current code is removing both "-"

```
Sub TrimCell()

Dim i As String
Dim k As String

i = "-"
k = ""

Columns("C").Replace what:=i, replacement:=k, lookat:=xlPart, 
MatchCase:=False

End Sub
```

The Excel function I have for this is `=REPLACE(C1,1,FIND("-",C1),"")`. This works but I want something in VBA.

Comment: Use InStr to find the first occurence of '-' and then return everything after that using Mid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work on column C:

```
Sub my_sub()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Range("C:C"))
  c = Trim(Mid(c, InStr(c, "-") + 1))
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the location of the first "-"

```
location = instr(1, cells(iRow,3), "-", vbTextCompare)
```

Taking advantage of fact that instr only returns the first entry...
Then trim the cell to the right using that location

```
if location > 0 then
    'Found a "-" within this cell

     cells(iRow,3) = right(cells(iRow,3), len(cells(iRow,3)-location)

end if
```

iRows is obviously just my iterator over the rows in your data. Define it whatever way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function replaceFirstGroup(x As String) As String
    Dim arr
    arr = Split(x, " - ")
    arr(0) = "###$"
    replaceFirstGroup = Join(Filter(arr, "###$", False), " - ")
End Function
```

It can be called/tested in this way:

```
Sub testReplaceFirstGroup()
  Dim x As String
  x = "123 - abc - xyz"
  MsgBox replaceFirstGroup(x)
End Sub
```

In order to process C:C column, using the above function, please use the next code. It should be extremely fast using an array, working in memory and dropping the processing result at once:

```
Sub ProcessCCColumn()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastR = sh.Range("C" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 
 arr = sh.Range("C2:C" & lastR).value
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    arr(i, 1) = replaceFirstGroup(CStr(arr(i, 1)))
 Next i
 sh.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).value = arr
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could dot it in one go using Evaluate.

```vb
  With Range("C1", Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .Value = Evaluate("MID(" & .Address & ", FIND(""-"", " & .Address & ")+1, LEN(" & .Address & "))")
  End With
```